# How to achieve cross domain tracking on my own web analytic site?

Tags: javascript, analytics

I would like someone to point me to good resources on how to  track activity on other sites that belong to me that are on other domains.
I have searched for information on this topic but have been unable to find anything other than when using Google Analytics.

I have not tried anything other than looking at sending some specific header information.

Comment: And Google Analytics is not enough? You can use your web-server logs, or analogues of GA like Matomo, Adobe Analytics, Tealium, etc.

Comment: I would like to roll my own analytics for the challenge

Comment: Well you should be more specific in your questioning. If you want to keep it vague, you're welcome to go look more into how to implement something like this here: https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo It's the source of Matomo.